# How to call all base class destructors? (or a common function)

Tags: c++, templates, derived-class

I'm wondering if any elegant way to do this;

```
template<typename tType>
class A
{
   ...
};

class B : A<type1>, A<type2>, A<type3> ...
{
public:
  void CallBaseDestructors()
  {
    A<type1>::~A();
    A<type2>::~A();
    A<type3>::~A();
    ...

    //Or Something like that...

    A<type1>::DoSomething();
    A<type2>::DoSomething();
    A<type3>::DoSomething();
    ...
  }
};
```

It don't have to be destructor. It is also OK, if a function like `A<>::Foo()` can be called from `B`, but not extra call (code line) for each base (loop is ok).

Comment: They will be all called when `B` destructor is called.

Comment: You really should not be calling the destructor yourself.  The compiler will do it for you.  That said, how is this not working for you?

Comment: I dont want to delete 'B', and not deleting 'B' or bases. It dont have to be a call to base destructor, it is also ok a call to a function from the base. But i dont want to write a call for each base class.

Comment: C++ doesn't have reflection so unless you inherit from a parameter pack you have to specify them yourself.

Comment: @YusufR.Karagöz: "*I dont want to delete 'B'*" Then why do you want to destroy the base class subobjects of `B`? Your question is very confused.

Comment: Unless you are writing some code involving `placement new`, calling destructors manually is *extremely* likely to be a bug (in fact; I don't recall ever having seen an explicit destructor call outside of "placement new" context that was not flat out *wrong* (and this does not look like an exception)). You are doing it wrong.

Comment: This is [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please rephrase your question describing what kind functionality `B` should provide.

Comment: The destructor and constructor are special functions. Don't use them as an example of what You want to achieve. Please improve the question and explain what You are actually trying to do.

Comment: do you actually wanted to ask: How do I destroy a `B` instance when it inherits from many base classes ?? Its much easier than you think, in most cases you dont have to do anything

Comment: You simply never call base class desctructors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<class ...tTypes>
class A;

template<>
class A<>
{
  void Reset()  {}
};

template<class tType, class ...tTypes>
class A<tType, tTypes...> : A<tTypes...>
{
  void Reset()
  {
    //Reset Impl for this type

    A<tTypes...>::Reset(); //And rest
  }
};

using tBase = A<type1, type2, type3, typeN>;

class B final : tBase 
{
};
```

That helped me. It is a generic class  which calls Reset from each base.
Note: Code is psuedo. (public keywords and so on needed)

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you shouldn't be manually invoking base class destructors like that. Calling the destructor is for "hardcore" work with placement new; your example is a bug, because you're going to end up destroying things "twice" and your program has undefined behaviour.

On to the crux of the question: how to repeat some given function call for all bases, without writing them all out? I'm afraid you can't (unless you inherited from a parameter pack). C++ doesn't have *reflection*, which might otherwise have permitted you to loop over the base class types.

Fortunately it's a very rare thing to want to do, and even then it's rare to have *so many bases* that a few repeated lines is a problem. And, again, here you haven't presented a good case for it.